# Clickable Qlabel How to use inside Designer

Tags: c++, qt

I need to make `Qlabel` clickable, which basically I used to display images in my main window, by googling I found that I need to create a subclass for the `Qlabel`, according to this link https://wiki.qt.io/Make-a-QLabel-Clickable.

My question is how can use this custom class inside my UI designer, is it possible ? Or I have to manage this UI element by code only?

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks
Haris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Qt Desiger, you have to create a `QLabel` and then "promote" it to the `ClickableLabel` class.

To do so, right-click the QLAbel object instantiated in your widget, select "Promote widget..." and specify `ClickableLabel` class name and path to the header file defining it.

Note that, both header and source files for `ClickableLabel` must be part of your Qt project.

This should simply work!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, actually my UI contains 10  QLabel items, using the above method should create 10 classes corresponding to each Qlabel

Comment: You need to promote the 10 `QLabel`, creating 10 `ClickableLabel` objects. Now, if you really have 10 objects, you can also leave an empty layout in your .ui and add the labels programatically from the class constructor (the one instantiating the .ui) using a `for` loop. Then you directly create the `ClickableLabel` objects and add them to the orignally empty layout (using `addWidget`).

Answer (score 1):

Using your link provided, I made my `main()` as below :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;
    ClickableLabel *MyLable = new ClickableLabel("Amol",w);
    MyLable->show();
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Important point is, as you customize your widget you need to pass `parent pointer` to the Custom widget,that is `MainWindow` here. Once you customize widget you need to give all its attributes programatically. Please add respective `.h` and `.cpp` for `ClickableLabel`class in your project.
Hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that UI designer refers to the QT Creator...

You can promote standard QLabel to clickable label following way:

1. Create ClickableLabel -class.
2. Create standard QLabel -widget in the QT Creator.
3. Click right mouse button on the top of the new QLabel-widget in the form editor and select "Promote to".
4. Enter name of the earlier created ClickableLabel -class to the Promoted class name -field. The dialog fills automatically also header file -field based on the name of the class.
5. Press Add-button.
6. Select a new promoted class from the list and press "Promote" -button.

Now the QLabel-widget, created on the step 2, is actually ClickableLabel-object.